# protocol-buffers: fully qualified import names

Tags: protocol-buffers

While reading https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto I ran into the following piece of text:

> The protocol compiler searches for imported files in a set of
> directories specified on the protocol compiler command line using the
> -I/--proto_path flag. If no flag was given, it looks in the directory in which the compiler was invoked. In general you should set the
> --proto_path flag to the root of your project and use fully qualified names for all imports.

What exactly do they mean that *--proto_path* should point at the root of the project, and use fully-qualified import names?

For example my project tree has the following structure:

```
$HOME/
    my_project/
       docs/
       src/
       lib/
       proto/
         p1.proto
         p2.proto
```

`proto` is where I keep `.proto` schemas. So for the above layout I should call *protoc* as *--proto_path=$HOME/my_project/proto* ? Not sure what should import look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `--proto_path=$HOME/my_project/proto` and you should try this to prove it to yourself.

There are 2 "paths" that are important and I think I've not seen it documented:

1. the `proto_path`(s) which are the path(s) on the local file system to the root (!) of the import path of protos
2. the import paths extending from the `proto_path`(s) to specific proto files.

Extending your example. If you wanted to namespace the protos `foo.protobuf` such that `p1.proto` and `p2.proto` included `package foo.protobuf;`, `p1.proto` and `p2.proto` would need to be placed in subdirectory `foo/protobuf` **beneath** `my_project/proto` and the `proto_path` would be **unchanged**.

This can be seen with Google's [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf). These are in `protoc/include` alongside `protoc/bin` and each proto is in the subdirectory `google/protobuf` because each e.g. [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Any) is `package google.protobuf;`.

Unfortunately (!) the well-known types are confusingly (usually) not included in `proto_path` because they are in a (well-)known location for `protoc`. However, they are implicitly (and you can explicitly references them as) `--proto_path=/path/to/protoc/include`